# Get index of element in array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Observe the following schemata:

```
Client {
 name: String
}

Votes {
 start: Date,
 end: Date,
 clients: [
  client: Client,
  votes: Number
 ]
}
```

**Is it possible to get the index of a certain 'Client' in 'votes.clients' without returning the whole array?**

My use case is the following. The 'clients' array is ordered by number of votes.  There could be hundreds of thousands of elements in the array. I need to quickly get the positions by number of votes for certain clients for a certain period. For example: 'Yesterday client John ranked 205th by number of votes.

Answer (score 0):

As you're ordering the clients array at some point, you can keep the index value inside the sub-document.

```
 clients: [
            {
                client: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Client'},
                votes: {type: Number},
                index: {type: Number}
            }
        ]
```

And using [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) in aggregation framework will return only those sub-documents that match the filter criteria and they will contain the index.

```
Vote.aggregate( [{ $match: {end: "2016-10-14T19:39:52.476Z"}},
    {
        $project: {
            clients: {
                $filter: {
                    input: '$clients',
                    as: 'client',
                    cond: {$gt: ['$$client.votes', 50]}
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```